# Flutter web showing blank on using singleChildScrollView when deploying web app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Flutter web doesn't shows any error when using debug mode but when relesed it shows blank screen.

Following is the code:

```
class _AboutUsState extends State<AboutUs> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var pad = EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.15);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.grey,
              )),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
          title: Text(\\ widget here
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.1, right: width * 0.1),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // widgets here                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I have also attached an image.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: does it happen only when using `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: Yes. Anything that includes scroll. ( listview etc )

Comment: ok try just for testing `body:` with `Column` that has three children: `Text`, `Expanded > ListView` and `Text` - do you see only two `Text`s on the top and bottom and nothing between them?

Comment: Expanded works fine when in between.

Comment: I think height was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is blank because you didn't define any height for the listview.

To using the list view, you should define its width and height.
For testing, try to wrap it with the container and give it height and width.

```
return 
   Container(
     width:500,
     height:1000,
     child: Listview(
    children:[childA(),childB,etc()]));
```